# how to create a simple driver? [Ubuntu]

Tags: c, linux-kernel, driver, ubuntu-16.04, kernel-module

The idea is to create a driver and a user application which can communicate through a device.

When I compile the module, attach it to the kernel and create the device, I don't get any error, but when I launch the user app, it crashes. Also, after the crash, my computer gets slower and sometimes even I need to reboot my system.
I also have read the kernel log file, and found this error: `[  336.741386] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at (null)`

Can you please tell me if there's something wrong with my code?

## Driver code:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>           // Allows to open/read/write/execute a device
#include <linux/cdev.h>         // Char driver; makes cdev available
#include <linux/semaphore.h>    // Used to access semaphores; used for synchronization for avoiding crashes
#include <asm/uaccess.h>        // Copy_to_user;copy_from_user

struct fake_device{
    char data[100];
    struct semaphore sem;
}virtual_device;

struct cdev *mcdev;     // My Char device driver
int major_number;
int ret;

dev_t dev_num;

#define DEVICE_NAME "looperdevice"

int device_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp){
    if(down_interruptible(&virtual_device.sem) != 0){
        printk(KERN_ALERT "looperdevice: could not lock device during open");
        return -1;
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "looperdevice: opened device");
    return 0;

}
ssize_t device_read(struct file* filp, char* bufStoreData, size_t bufCount, loff_t* curOffset){
    printk(KERN_INFO "looperdevice: Reading from device");
    ret = copy_to_user(bufStoreData, virtual_device.data, bufCount);
    return ret;
}

ssize_t device_write(struct file* filp, const char* bufSourceData, size_t bufCount, loff_t* curOffset){
    printk(KERN_INFO "looperdevice: Writing to device");
    ret = copy_from_user(virtual_device.data, bufSourceData, bufCount);
    return ret;
}

int device_close(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp){
    printk(KERN_INFO "looperdevice: Closing device");
    up(&virtual_device.sem); // Set semaphore up
    return 0;
}


struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner =    THIS_MODULE,
    .open = device_open,
    .release = device_close,
    .write = device_write,
    .read = device_read
};

static int driver_entry(void){
    /*
    Register our device in the system
    alloc_chrdev_region(dev_t*, uint fminor, uint count, char* name)
    */
    ret = alloc_chrdev_region(&dev_num, 0, 1, DEVICE_NAME); // Will store minor and max number into dev_num, for future extraction
    if (ret < 0){
        printk(KERN_ALERT "looperdevice: failed to allocate a major number");
        return ret;
    }
    // Extracting major number
    major_number = MAJOR(dev_num);
    printk(KERN_INFO "looperdevice: major_number extracted, %d", major_number);
    printk(KERN_INFO "\tuse \"mknod /dev/%s c %d 0\" for device file",DEVICE_NAME, major_number);

    mcdev = cdev_alloc(); // Create our cdev structure already initializated
    mcdev->ops = &fops;     // struct file operations
    mcdev->owner = THIS_MODULE;
    // Now that we created the cdev we have to add it to the kernel
    // int cdev_add(struct cdev* dev, dev_t num, unsigned int count)
    ret = cdev_add(mcdev, dev_num, 1);
    if (ret < 0){
        printk(KERN_ALERT "looperdevice: unable to add cdev to kernel");
        return ret;

    }
    // Initialize our semaphore
    sema_init(&virtual_device.sem, 1);

    return 0;
}
static void driver_exit(void){
    cdev_del(mcdev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(dev_num,1);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "looperdevice: Unloaded module");

}

module_init(driver_entry);
module_exit(driver_exit);
```

## User Application code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define DEVICE "/dev/looperdevice"

int main(){
    int i, fd, ch;
    char write_buf[100], read_buf[100];
    fd = open(DEVICE, O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1){
        printf("file %s either does not exist or has been locked by another process\n", DEVICE);
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("Looper application v0.1 Beta\n");
    while (ch != 3){
        printf("--------------MENU-------------\n");
        printf("1. Read from device\n2. Write to device\n3. Exit");
        printf("Choose an option: ");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        switch(ch){
            case 1:
                // reading from device
                read(fd, read_buf, sizeof(read_buf));
                printf("DEVICE: %s\n", read_buf);
                break;
            case 2:
                // Writing to device
                printf("Enter Data: ");
                gets(write_buf);
                write(fd, write_buf, sizeof(write_buf));
                break;
            case 3:
                exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid option\n");
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## KERNEL LOG FILE:

```
[  321.242532] driver: module license 'unspecified' taints kernel.
[  321.242534] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[  321.243024] looperdevice: major_number extracted, 241
[  321.243026]  use "mknod /dev/looperdevice c 241 0" for device file
[  321.243028] looperdevice: unable to add cdev to kernel
[  336.741386] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at                                           (null)
[  336.741524] IP: __down_interruptible+0x51/0xf0
[  336.741563] PGD a3279067 
[  336.741564] PUD a3278067 
[  336.741589] PMD 0 

[  336.741650] Oops: 0002 [#1] SMP
[  336.741680] Modules linked in: driver(POE) ccm bnep pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) dm_crypt dell_wmi sparse_keymap uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core videodev media dell_laptop dell_smbios btusb dcdbas btrtl btbcm btintel dell_smm_hwmon bluetooth arc4 iwldvm mac80211 intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_codec_hdmi coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_codec_generic aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm input_leds snd_seq_midi joydev snd_seq_midi_event serio_raw snd_rawmidi snd_seq binfmt_misc iwlwifi snd_seq_device snd_timer cfg80211
[  336.742291]  lpc_ich shpchp snd mei_me soundcore mei wmi dell_smo8800 mac_hid dell_rbtn parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid i915 ahci libahci psmouse i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper sdhci_pci sdhci syscopyarea sysfillrect e1000e sysimgblt fb_sys_fops drm ptp pps_core fjes video
[  336.742530] CPU: 2 PID: 3578 Comm: app Tainted: P           OE   4.10.0-37-generic #41~16.04.1-Ubuntu
[  336.742607] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Latitude E5430 vPro/0NVFXC, BIOS A16 08/19/2015
[  336.742673] task: ffff96ace1e08000 task.stack: ffffb4d500b68000
[  336.742727] RIP: 0010:__down_interruptible+0x51/0xf0
[  336.742771] RSP: 0018:ffffb4d500b6bba0 EFLAGS: 00010046
[  336.742817] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffffffc0be84c8 RCX: 0000000000000002
[  336.742878] RDX: ffffffffc0be84d0 RSI: 0000000000000292 RDI: ffffffffc0be84c8
[  336.742938] RBP: ffffb4d500b6bbe8 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[  336.742998] R10: 00000000000000f1 R11: ffff96acaa4d6338 R12: 7fffffffffffffff
[  336.743058] R13: ffff96ace1e08000 R14: ffff96ace294eb00 R15: ffffffffaf9c5c80
[  336.743120] FS:  00007fadeade0700(0000) GS:ffff96ad5e300000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  336.743188] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  336.743237] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 00000000a337a000 CR4: 00000000001406e0
[  336.743298] Call Trace:
[  336.743329]  ? exact_lock+0x11/0x20
[  336.743363]  down_interruptible+0x4b/0x60
[  336.743403]  device_open+0x15/0x30 [driver]
[  336.743442]  chrdev_open+0xbf/0x1b0
[  336.743477]  do_dentry_open+0x208/0x310
[  336.743514]  ? cdev_put+0x30/0x30
[  336.743548]  vfs_open+0x4c/0x70
[  336.743581]  ? may_open+0x9b/0x100
[  336.743620]  path_openat+0x2ac/0x1430
[  336.743660]  ? page_add_file_rmap+0x58/0x140
[  336.743702]  do_filp_open+0x91/0x100
[  336.743738]  ? __alloc_fd+0x46/0x170
[  336.743774]  do_sys_open+0x12d/0x280
[  336.743809]  SyS_open+0x1e/0x20
[  336.743841]  entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x1e/0xad
[  336.743883] RIP: 0033:0x7fadea912010
[  336.743916] RSP: 002b:00007ffcf9ce3238 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000002
[  336.743982] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 00007fadea912010
[  336.744042] RDX: 00007ffcf9ce3428 RSI: 0000000000000002 RDI: 00000000004009b8
[  336.746348] RBP: 00007ffcf9ce3330 R08: 00000000004009a0 R09: 00007fadeabf5ab0
[  336.748583] R10: 000000000000069d R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 00000000004006b0
[  336.750831] R13: 00007ffcf9ce3410 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[  336.753533] Code: 00 00 48 83 e4 f0 48 83 ec 30 65 48 8b 04 25 28 00 00 00 48 89 44 24 28 31 c0 48 8b 47 10 48 89 14 24 48 89 67 10 48 89 44 24 08 <48> 89 20 4c 89 6c 24 10 c6 44 24 18 00 eb 38 4d 85 e4 7e 52 49 
[  336.758651] RIP: __down_interruptible+0x51/0xf0 RSP: ffffb4d500b6bba0
[  336.761183] CR2: 0000000000000000
[  336.775501] ---[ end trace 3fcbe3000944b329 ]---
```

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: `When I compile the module, attach it to the kernel and create the device, I don't get any error` - According to the log, you **got an error** when load the module into the kernel: `looperdevice: unable to add cdev to kernel`. According to the driver's code, the module's loading should be cancelled (as negative value is returned), so futher "BUG" looks suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the module license:

```
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Thank you :)